# In Python, how can I run another Python script from the main script at the same time and close it when I stop the main script?

Tags: python

```
import subprocess 

subprocess.Popen('python', 'second_script.py')
```

Does this open the second script and makes them run concurrently? Also will it close the second script if I stop the main one? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: When parent processes are destroyed so are all its subprocesses. I think all subprocesses are asynchronous.

Comment: Well, did you try your own code? If the main script ends it kills the subprocesses... `Popen` is non-blocking (main will keep running) while `subprocess.call` is blocking (will hold main until the subprocess finishes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you need.

If you want to use some functions that are coded in 'pythonScriptA.py' in another script 'pythonScriptB.py', you can import the first script:

```py
from pythonScriptA import *

# Use the functions in the ScriptB
```

If you want two script to run concurrently/in parallel, you should look into the multiprocessing library, or in any other library that allow python code to be run on multiple threads.

--
Edit: correction of the script

Comment: Sorry, terrible at explaining. But as an example. I want to do a loop in main.py, but I want to do another loop in second_script.py. So I wanted to run them concurrently/in parallel. BUT when main.py stops running at any point, second_script.py will close itself or have main.py force close second_script.py when it stops. I'm not sure if this was any clearer q-q

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry I'm a bit more in c++ these days, force of habit. I edited my code thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

pid = subprocess.Popen(['second-script']).pid
print(f'pid={pid}')
...
# do whatever you have to do here
```